# Automatically show one selection of a field based on the selection of another field in a view

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

Sorry if this is a repeat question but I'm stuck!

Ok, I have a content type named 'Media' that is basically a bunch of videos, pictures, podcasts as well as a small write up that explains what it is. I have a view that lists these media files according to most recently added. My problem is that in this view, I display an icon according to whichever type of media it is (a camera logo for videos, and podcast logo for podcasts, etc.) but I have to choose which one it is every time I create a new 'Media' content type.

I have a field called 'icons' within this 'Media' content type, which is just a term reference with a select list widget. The taxonomy terms are the file types (video, podcast, picture) and they are linked to the correct image/logo/thumbnail whatever you want to call it.

What I want to do is have it so that when I am adding a new 'Media' content type, it will automatically figure out the correct image/logo to display once I select the type of Media it is (the 'type' is a list(float) field and also uses a select widget). I hope this makes sense!

Comment: if I understand the question properly, you should be able to create a relationship to the term reference field, thereby being able to include the image/logo/thumbnail directly as a field in the view

Comment: Oh, so thaat's what relationship is for! Wow, I will have to read and figure out how to do that, thanks!

Comment: relationships are quite powerful - they let you connect data about a node to the author for example, basically any other data elements within the node, user or whatever the view shows, so long as there is some connection - in your case a term reference which needs to be accessed on its own accord because it is essentially its own node and data structure, which is why it doesn't necessarily show as a field of its own until the relationship is established

Answer (score 0):

Take a look towards conditional fields module. Hope this will helps to solve your issue.
(https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)